# Array Access outside Method

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a method that parses a text file, and based on the results of the parse, it defines and populates about 12 arrays. And I need to access those arrays outside the method.

Now, if it was ONE array, I'd just return the array. But it's 12 arrays.

And I can't define the arrays outside the method, because I don't know the dimensions until I run the method to parse the text file, which tells me how many elements in the arrrays.

I could return a huge List<> of all those arrays I suppose, but that seems incredibly kludgy.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Are they "named" arrays? I.e. do they have different contents and purposes? If so, how about a class with the arrays as members? If they're just a list of arrays, then return them as such.

Comment: I would stay with List<array_type[]>. or more generic List<object[]>

Comment: Returning a list of 12 arrays isn't huge. It's only a list of 12.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah, I think you're right. I just had visions of Add'ing 12 arrays to a list and it just seemed a bit of a mess, when all I need is external access. And also my nicely-named arrays get hidden in the List<>.

Comment: @J.McCabe I would still go with the class route...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks...I'm trying to think thru the class thing. The arrays as properties in a class, but I instantiate them in the method? I have to instantiate in the method because that's where I parse the dimensions. I'm getting a headache :)

Comment: @J.McCabe Yeah, that won't cause you any problems though. Create the class itself in the method as well and return it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET In my best Homer Simpson....DOH !!! Brilliant, that'll do nicely. Thanks all.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  Oh wait, you can't create a class in a method...maybe I should cancel this for tonight and work on it tomorrow :)

Comment: @J.McCabe Sorry, should have been more clear. You have to define the class elsewhere, but you can *instantiate* the class inside the method, then assign its properties to your parsed arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, honestly it seems perfectly fine and not bad at all. As you said in your comments, just have your method do something like this. I'll assume you have 12 arrays of `string`:

```
public List<string[]> GetStuffFromTextFile(File file){
    // Use your favorite file reader to get an array. Some pseudo-code here.
    // I don't know how you'll get the data.
    string[] array1 = GetSomeDataFromFile1(file);
    string[] array2 = GetSomeDataFromFile2(file);
    string[] array3 = GetSomeDataFromFile3(file);
    string[] array4 = GetSomeDataFromFile4(file);
    string[] array5 = GetSomeDataFromFile5(file);
    string[] array6 = GetSomeDataFromFile6(file);
    string[] array7 = GetSomeDataFromFile7(file);
    string[] array8 = GetSomeDataFromFile8(file);
    string[] array9 = GetSomeDataFromFile9(file);
    string[] array10 = GetSomeDataFromFile10(file);
    string[] array11 = GetSomeDataFromFile11(file);
    string[] array12 = GetSomeDataFromFile12(file);    

    return new List<string[]>{array1,array2,array3,array4,array5,array6,array7,array8,array9,array10,array11,array12}
};
```

This seems pretty bad from a maintenance perspective since tomorrow there could be 13 arrays, in which case you should use a loop of sorts to gather up all the individual arrays and put them in a `List<string[]>`.

In my opinion, you should just make a class that you return from the method.

```
public class FileData{
   string[] array1 {get; set;}
 //...
   string[] array12 {get; set;}

}
```

And somewhere outside the class, probably in your method, you just do this:

```
public FileData GetStuffFromTextFile(File file){
    FileData fileData = new FileData();
    fileData.array1 = GetSomeDataFromFile1(file);
    \\ ...
    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: Ideally with better names than array1-12 :)

Comment: Yeah @BradleyDotNET totally. Just had no context from OP :P

Comment: I'd actually make `FileData`'s constructor private and make `GetStuffFromFile` a static method of the class with a more factory driven name: `CreateFromFile` or some such.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. The class design is not exceptional by any means but I just created it to illustrate the idea of encapsulating the data in a class as opposed to a `List<string[]>`.